# php table checkboxes doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, forms, submit

I have a table where I am displaying data from mysql. On the first column I have a checkbox. My php code is going to do something with the selected rows, but the problem is that my submit form doesn't work and i don't know why.

HTML code:

```
    echo "<div class='container-fluid'>
  <div class='table-responsive'>
  <table class='fancyTable' id='myTable05'>
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Aviz</th>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>Denumire produs</th>
      <th>Pret RON</th>
      <th>U/M</th>
      <th>Cantitate</th>
      <th>Firma</th>
      <th>Delegat</th>
      <th>Mentiuni1</th>
      <th>Mentiuni2</th>
      <th>Cota TVA</th>
      <th>Vsaloare</th>
      <th>TVA</th>
      <th>Facturat RON</th>
      <th>Termen plata</th>
      <th>Persoana contact</th>
      <th>Pret ofertat</th>
      <th>Reducere acordata</th>
      <th>Nr comanda</th>
      <th>Termen de livrare</th>
      <th>Nr zile scadente ramase</th>
    </tr></thead>";
    while($row_comanda_afisare = mysqli_fetch_array($result_comanda_afisare)){
      echo "<tbody><tr class='grid'>
      <td>
      <form action='includes/aviz.inc.php' method='post'>
        <input type='checkbox' name='aviz_id[]' value='". $row_comanda_afisare['id']. "' />

      </td>
      <td>". $row_comanda_afisare['id']. "</td>";
      echo "<td>". $row_comanda_afisare['denumire_produs']. "</td>";
      echo "<td>". $row_comanda_afisare['pretRON']. "</td>";
      echo "<td>". $row_comanda_afisare['U_M']. "</td>";
      echo "<td>". $row_comanda_afisare['cantitate']. "</td>";
      echo "<td>". $row_comanda_afisare['firma']. "</td>";
      echo "<td>". $row_comanda_afisare['delegat']. "</td>";
      echo "<td>". $row_comanda_afisare['mentiuni1']. "</td>";
      echo "<td>". $row_comanda_afisare['mentiuni2']. "</td>";
      echo "<td>". $row_comanda_afisare['cota_tva']. "</td>";
      echo "<td>". $row_comanda_afisare['valoare']. "</td>";
      echo "<td>". $row_comanda_afisare['tva']. "</td>";
      echo "<td>". $row_comanda_afisare['facturatRON']. "</td>";
      echo "<td>". $row_comanda_afisare['termen_plata']. "</td>";
      echo "<td>". $row_comanda_afisare['persoana_contact']. "</td>";
      echo "<td>". $row_comanda_afisare['pret_ofertat']. "</td>";
      echo "<td>". $row_comanda_afisare['reducere']. "</td>";
      echo "<td>". $row_comanda_afisare['nr_comanda']. "</td>";
      echo "<td>". $row_comanda_afisare['termen_livrare']. "</td>";
      //numarul de zile scadente
      $sql_date = "SELECT DATEDIFF(termen_livrare, CURRENT_DATE) FROM comanda WHERE id=$row_comanda_afisare[id]";
      $result_date = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_date);
      while($row_date = mysqli_fetch_array($result_date)){
        $zile_scadente = $row_date['DATEDIFF(termen_livrare, CURRENT_DATE)'];
      }
      echo '<td>'.$zile_scadente. '</td></tr>';
    }
    echo "<input type='submit' value='aviz'></form></tbody></table></div></div></div>";
    ?>
    <script src="lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.fixedheadertable.js"></script>
    <script>
    $('#myTable05').fixedHeaderTable({
        altClass: 'odd',
        footer: true,
        fixedColumns: 1,
    });
    </script>
    </section>
```

The problem is that when i press on the submit button it is not taking me to the includes/aviz.inc.php file...does anyone know why?

Comment: because you have the `<form>` inside the loop, therefore have messed up html with several opening forms, only one closing.

Comment: Oh, it is working now, thanks so much. I have the opening tags but they are in the header.php file and i posted only the relevant code.